# Is there a solution to this system for the diagonal matrix?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, markov-process

I'm trying to find a solution to a system of equations, but its quite different from anything I've come across before. I believe there is a solution, but I could be wrong.

$\mathbf{A} = \mathrm{diag}(\mathbf{a})$ is an $n \times n$ diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries $\mathbf{a}_i \in [0,1]$ are the unknown quantities in my system. The equation is as follows:
$$ \mathbf{p}^T [ \mathbb{I} - \mathbf{T} + \mathbf{AT}]^{-1}\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{c}^T$$
where $\mathbf{p}$ is an $n$-vector of initial state probabilities, $\mathbf{T}$ is an $n \times n$ transition matrix of probabilities whose rows sum to one, and $\mathbf{c}$ is an $n$-vector of capacities. The above equation is based on an absorbing markov chain, and the idea is that it represents a model where capacity is limited, and in equilibrium, the acceptance probabilities $a_i$ "clear the market" so that no absorbing state is overfull. The equals sign should actually be an inequality but I'm trying to solve a simpler version for now.

I need to solve for $\mathbf{A}$. I don't know a lot about linear algebra, but I don't think that systems usually look like this, and you don't usually try to solve for the matrix. However, since the matrix is diagonal there are actually only $n$ equations in $n$ unknowns. The vector $\mathbf{a}$ is actually what I'm interested in, but I couldn't see another way to make it work in matrix notation.

I have got as far as
$$ \mathbf{p}^T = \mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{A}^{-1} - \mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{T} + \mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{T} $$
but now I'm hopelessly stuck. I hope someone can help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to solve the last eqaution I don't see any problem here. 
Define $x=A^{-1}c$. 
Then you have 
$$
p-T^Tc=(I-T^T)x 
$$
Solve it. (Take in account that $I-T^T$ probably is singular).

Recover $A$ from $x$

The only problem I observe is to guarantee ($a\in [0,1]$. Does it follow from the nature of the problem or not?

Comment: Thank you! I tried it and it works perfectly, although it is singular as you said so I had to use row reduction. What made you realise that it would be singular?

Comment: $T$ has 1 eigenvalue and $I$ has all 1s. Difference must have some eigenvalue $0$

Comment: Hi Alexander,I've posted a follow up [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/901848/follow-up-on-solution-to-markov-process-equation). Its the same problem, but with more than one group of people.