# Follow-up on solution to Markov process equation

Tags: matrices, markov-chains, economics, markov-process

I asked a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/897488/is-there-a-solution-to-this-system-for-the-diagonal-matrix) about solving a system related to an absorbing Markov chain. I now have a variation where there are $m$ types (of student, job seeker, etc) each of which applies to institutions in a different order, and the total accepted by the institutions has to respect capacities $\mathbf{c}$. So, whereas the original was of the form (after some manipulation):
$$
\mathbf{p}^T [\mathbb{I} - \mathbf{T} + \mathbf{A}\mathbf{T}]^{-1}\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{c}^T
$$
The new form is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^m \mathbf{p}_i^T [\mathbb{I} - \mathbf{T}_i + \mathbf{A}\mathbf{T}_i]^{-1}\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{c}^T
$$
or in matrix notation
$$
\mathbf{p}^T [\mathbb{I} - \mathbf{T} + \mathbf{A}^*\mathbf{T}]^{-1}\mathbf{A}^*\mathbf{S} = \mathbf{c}^T
$$
where $\mathbf{p} = (\mathbf{p}_1,\mathbf{p}_2,\dots,\mathbf{p}_m)^T$ is an $mn$-vector of initial state probabilities, $\mathbf{T} = \mathrm{diag}(\mathbf{T}_1,\mathbf{T}_2,\dots,\mathbf{T}_m)$ is an $mn \times mn$ block diagonal matrix of transition probabilities, with rows summing to 1. $\mathbf{c}$ is still an $n$-vector of capacities. $\mathbf{S} = (\mathbb{I},\mathbb{I},\dots,\mathbb{I})^T$ is the $mn \times n$ summing matrix.

$\mathbf{A}^* = \mathrm{diag}(\mathbf{A},\mathbf{A},\dots,\mathbf{A})$ is just a replication of $\mathbf{A}$ which is itself a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $\mathbf{a} = (a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)^T$. These diagonal entries, the acceptance probabilities, are the only unknowns in the system and the quantities of interest.

Whereas before I could take $[\mathbb{I} - \mathbf{T} + \mathbf{A}\mathbf{T}]^{-1}\mathbf{A}$ over to the other side, I now can't because of the summation, which makes it more difficult. I still have reason to believe there is a solution for $\mathbf{a}$, although I could be wrong.

Note you can do:
$$
\mathbf{p}^T [\mathbb{I} - \mathbf{T} + \mathbf{A}^*\mathbf{T}]^{-1}\mathbf{S} = \mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{A}^{-1}
$$
where the $\mathbf{A}$ that has been taken across is the small version. For what its worth.

I hope someone can help.

P.s. I will also accept answers that show that this is not solvable or not linear in $\mathbf{a}$.

Comment: I have a question. If $A=0$ then $c=0$. Is it ok in your framework as an extreme case? Now if $A=I$ then $\sum_i p_i =c$. Is it also consistent?

Comment: In the original problem you had $(I-T+AT)^{-1}$. Now you have $(I-T+TA)^{-1}$. Where is the correct version?

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake somewhere. I think I thought that I'd made a mistake in the original, but I actually made a mistake in this one.

Comment: Edited. I've verified this version is correct.

Comment: Yes, the extreme cases you mentioned are both consistent.